# using watin to automate business objects reports

Tags: watin, business-objects

how can i use watin to test business object reports in case all page render auto generated every run as the following 
iD="generated number"+_string text

text field ID="12213124_sadfafs";

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your *string* (eg: sadfafs) is known, use a RegEx for the Find parameter.

Something like:  Find.ById(new Regex(regex_for_ends_with_sadfafs))

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your answer